# Эвент для динамического элемента

Tags: c#

Создаю множество элементов WebBrowser с помощью вот этого кода.

```
WebBrowser newweb = new WebBrowser();
myTabPage.Controls.Add(newweb);
```

Как на такой(динамически создаваемый) элемент, повесить событие? Например DocumentCompleted? И будет ли событие работать для каждого элемента в отдельности, или для всех сразу?

Comment: На события созданного объекта можно повесить обработчики. Делается это с помощью оператора `+=`. У каждого объекта будет своё событие (свой набор обработчиков). При этом обычно на все эти события вешается один единственный метод в качестве обработчика, но в своей программе Вы можете сделать, как Вам нужно.

Comment: А как можно передать методу переменную myTabPage?

Comment: С тех пор, как в C# появились лямбда-функции, удобнее всего через них. Например, заводите метод `HandleTabPageDocumentComplete(TabPage tabPage)`. После создания объекта `newweb` пишете `newweb.DocumentCompleted += (o, e) => { HandleTabPageDocumentComplete(myTabPage); };`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Подписывайтесь на событие каждого создаваемого экземпляра. Обработчики могут указывать на один и тот же метода (тогда обработчик будет вызываться при срабатывании события у *любого* компонента), а могут и на разные (тогда будет вызываться обработчик при срабатывании события у *конкретного* компонента). Пример единого обработчика:

```
WebBrowser newweb = new WebBrowser();
newweb.DocumentCompleted += DocumentCompletedHandler;
myTabPage.Controls.Add(newweb);
...
private void DocumentCompletedHandler(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Если `myTabPage` у вас один, то обращайтесь в `DocumentCompletedHandler` непосредственно к нему. Если же создаваемые компоненты кладутся в разные вкладки, то проще всего обращаться к родительскому элементу -- это и будет нужная вкладка.

```
private void DocumentCompletedHandler(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var webBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    var tabPage = (TabPage)webBrowser.Parent;
    ...
}
```

---

Если же нужно ассоциировать какие-то другие данные с компонентыми, то нужно каким-то способом надо сохранять пару "компонент-вкладка". Это можно сделать через свойство `Tag`:

```
WebBrowser newweb = new WebBrowser();
newweb.DocumentCompleted += DocumentCompletedHandler;
newweb.Tag = myTabPage;
myTabPage.Controls.Add(newweb);
...
private void DocumentCompletedHandler(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var webBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    var tabPage = (TabPage)webBrowser.Tag;
    ...
}
```

Можно через словарь: при создании добавляете запись, что такому-то компоненту соответствует такая-то вкладка, а затем извлекаете её по имени.

```
private Dictionary<string, TabPage> webTabPages = new Dictionary<string, TabPage>();
...
WebBrowser newweb = new WebBrowser();
newweb.DocumentCompleted += DocumentCompletedHandler;
webTabPages.Add(newweb.Name, myTabPage);
myTabPage.Controls.Add(newweb);
...
private void DocumentCompletedHandler(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var webBrowser = (WebBrowser)sender;
    var tabPage = webTabPages[webBrowser.Name];
    ...
}
```

Comment: `var tabPage = ((WebBrowser)sender).Parent;`

Comment: @Igor точно! За два года работы с бэкендом уже все выветрилось :). Обновил ответ.